# The field of rational function over the base field.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

If $K$ is an infinite field, and $K(x)$ is the field of rational function (in the indeterminate $x$), is it true that the extension $K(x)/K$ is a Galois extension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $x$ is not algebraic over $K$, $K(x)/K$ is not an algebraic extension, hence  not a Galois extension.